# Using data attributes with media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, custom-data-attribute

I have a page I am setting up so that it looks the image below on the widest resolution, however on smaller resolutions the page setup will change what images are being displayed on screen, so I wanted to use a media query and `data` attribute. Only problem is:

1. I am not sure if I am using the `data` attribute correctly, and
2. I have no idea how I would target the `<p>` tags with a selector so I can use `:after` to display the image of the badges after the text.

This cant use any jquery/jscript as a requirement so it's kind of a pain.
[Demo, it should be configured properly with bootstrap.](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/94/) (The image is linked correctly, but not being displayed due to the attr.)

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="main" class=" container">
<div class="row">
    <div class ="col-lg-6 " id="badgeBox"> 
        <div class ="col-lg-12" data-test="<a href='http://www.va.gov/'  target='_blank'><div class='badgeContainer'><img  id='va_badge' class =' badges img-responsive' src='http://i.imgur.com/BAbUq6v.jpg'alt='Veteran Affairs Badge'></a></div>"> </div>
         <span><p> U.S.  Department of Veteran's Affairs</p></span>

    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.badgeContainer {
width: 30%;
}    
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
//some selector that targets the p tag// :after {
content:"("attr(data-test) ")";
}
}
```

[image: Widest Resolution mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting content from a data attribute would work like this.. However, the data-test needs to be inside the `p` and you'll have the larger problem of encoding the HTML content inside `data-test`..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  p:after {
    content: attr(data-test);
  }
}
```

A more Bootstrap friendly approach would be to use the included utility classes (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to only show the image link at larger resolutions use `visible-lg`.

Here's a demo with both approaches: http://bootply.com/94916